# monotonically reducing euclidean distance

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the given image, if $a<\frac{\pi}{2}$ how can I prove that the distance to $T$ from any point $Q$ on $PX$ is less than $TX$? i.e.
given $ a<\frac{\pi}{2}-XTP/2$, $|QT|<|TX|$ for all  $Q \in PX$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the angle TQP as b, and TPQ as c. Since a < TPX, we have that $\sin b = \sin TQX > \sin a$.  We also have that: $\frac{|PT|}{\sin b} = \frac{|QT|}{\sin c}$ & $ \frac{|PT|}{\sin a} =\frac{|TX|}{\sin c}$. Therefore, $|QT|<|TX|$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such uneven distribution of genius seems unfair! lol

Comment: I am so sorry that this is not a correct proof, since b may be larger that $\pi/2$. In fact, I think |QT|>|TX| sometimes. Think about a triangle: $a = \frac{\pi}{3}, TPX = \frac{\pi}{6}, PTX = \frac{\pi}{2}$. (You may need another condition that TPX>a)

Comment: I was just noticing the same thing.. atleast I was examining the significance of a<π/2

Comment: I'm sorry, still cant figure out where the mistake in the proof is since sinb>sina since they all lie in the first 2 quadrants

Comment: $\sin 5\pi/6 < \sin \pi/3$

Comment: yes.. the sine wave.. sorry, ive been silly.

Comment: Not at all. This is quite confusing.